# How to increase array size

Tags: arrays, go

Suppose I have an array

```
array1 := [5]int {
    1,2,3,4,5,
}
```

And I need to increase this array size.

- How can I increase array size in `go` so that I can add additional element?

If I have another array

```
array2 := [5]int {
    6,7,8,9,10,
}
```

- How can I append `array2` with `array1`?

Then `array1` will print `[1,10]`

```
for i:=0; i<len(array1); i++ {
    fmt.Print(array1[i], "," )
}
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: Arrays are static. use [slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types).

Comment: The default reason for the negative vote is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Because this is covered in the basic documentation, (the [Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/), [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), the [Language Spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec), and a [blog post](http://blog.golang.org/slices) among others), people probably felt it fell under the first clause.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to 'resize' an array is to make a new one. You can use a slice which behaves much like an array, but is resized dynamically for you. You use the `append` method to add items to a slice.

```
slice1 := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
slice2 := []int{6,7,8,9,10}
slice1 = append(slice1, slice2...)
for v, _ := range slice1 {
   fmt.Println(v)
}
```